# How do I get the value from a service to a component?

Tags: angular, angular-services

I need to get the currentBalance from the currentAccount but am receiving the error:

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentAccount' of undefined.

I am able to display the balance on my HTML file using {{ currentAccount.currentBalance }} but is coming back as undefined when I include it into a function. My function works perfectly if I replace balance with a static number, just doesn't work with the currentBalance.

Here is my code in the TS file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, ValidatorFn, FormBuilder, AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';
import { ICustomerAccount } from 'src/app/customer/interfaces';
import { CustomerService } from 'src/app/customer/services/customer.service';
import { WireErrorComponent } from '../wire-error/wire-error.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-wire-start',
  templateUrl: './wire-start.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./wire-start.component.scss']
})

export class WireStartComponent implements OnInit{
  @Input() currentAccount: ICustomerAccount;
  currentBalance: string;
  maxAmount = 1000000;

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog,
              private _customerService: CustomerService,
              private formBuilder: FormBuilder
              ) { }

    wireStartForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    purpose: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    amount: ['', [Validators.max(this.maxAmount), this.customValidatorFn]]
  });

  customValidatorFn(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {
    const amount: number = control.value;
    const balance: number = Number(this.currentAccount.currentBalance);
    if (balance >= amount) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return {'amountMinError': true}
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.currentAccount = this._customerService.getSelectedAccount();
  }
}
```

Comment: please post the customer service file as well.

Comment: is the customerService is having  providedIn: 'root' ?

Comment: Hard to tell what is going on without seeing the code from the service, but if getSelectedAccount returns an observable, you need to subscribe to it

Comment: yes it is provided in root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are taking the currentAccount value as an Input for the component that's why may be binding of the value from the service would be returning a value properly, but the currentAccount may be has a data set from the Input()

Try setting the data of the currentAccount from the service from the component from where app-wire-start component is called (i.e From the parent component), and pass the service data as an input to the app-wire-start component like

`<app-wire-start [currentAccount]="currentAccountFromService"></app-wire-start>`

Answer (score 0):

the context of `this` in  custom validator is different . Try using the `arrrow` function which sets the `context` of `this` to class.

```
customValidatorFn = (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null =>{
    const amount: number = control.value;
    const balance: number = Number(this.currentAccount.currentBalance);
    if (balance >= amount) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return {'amountMinError': true}
    }
  }
```

Here is the working example : [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tlys4h)

Comment: When i added the arrow function, control could not be read and the functions after it could not be reached

Comment: @BDev14 check the demo. and paste the error you saw

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your work. It isn't able to read currentAccount or currentBalance for some reason. Saying that it is undefined in the function of customValidatorFn

Comment: @BDev14 can you create stackblitz ??